# Delphi how to load report stored in database

Tags: delphi, fastreport, interbase

I am trying to build a finance software in Delphi. For the database I used Interbase which I am using it for the first time since I used Firebird before.

Any way I am 80% done but I face a problem: I found that I can create a report with `.fr3` (FastReport) inside the database - everything is Ok.

I didn't find any solution how to load a stored report from the database into the project - something along the lines of this:

```
sReportFile := LoadFileFromDatabase ('ReportFiles', 'ReportFile', StrToInt(sID));
```

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: Just don't store the report in the database and everything will be much easier.

Comment: If you're using InterBase, and not Firebird, then please don't tag Firebird.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, it is not even database agnostic at all.

Comment: Guys im new in forum and i thought that people who used interbase and firebird had a solution by experience .. sorry next time i do it right

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
procedure TForm1.frxReport1LoadTemplate(Report: TfrxReport;
  const TemplateName: String);
var
  memStream:TMemoryStream;
  BookMark: TBookmark;
begin
   try
     memStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
     BookMark:=ADOTable1.GetBookmark;
     if ADOTable1.Locate('TemplateName', TemplateName, [loCaseInsensitive]) then
       begin
         ADOTable1ReportBLOB.SaveToStream(memStream);
         memStream.Position:=0;
         Report.LoadFromStream(memStream);
       end;
      ADOTable1.GotoBookmark(BookMark);
   finally
     memStream.Free;
     ADOTable1.FreeBookmark(BookMark);
   end;  
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  memStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
     if OpenDialog1.Execute then
       try
         memStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
         frxReport1.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
         frxReport1.SaveToStream(memStream);
         memStream.Position:=0;
         ADOTable1.Insert;
         ADOTable1TemplateName.AsString:=ExtractFileName(OpenDialog1.FileName);
         ADOTable1ReportBLOB.LoadFromStream(memStream);
         ADOTable1.Post;
       finally
         memStream.Free;
       end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  memStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
  memStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  frxReport1.InheritFromTemplate(ADOTable1TemplateName.AsString, imDelete);
  try
    memStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    frxReport1.SaveToStream(memStream);
    memStream.Position:=0;
    ADOTable1.Insert;
    ADOTable1TemplateName.AsString:=Edit1.Text;
    ADOTable1ReportBLOB.LoadFromStream(memStream);
    ADOTable1.Post;
  finally
    memStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  memStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
  try
    memStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    ADOTable1ReportBLOB.SaveToStream(memStream);
    memStream.Position:=0;
    frxReport1.LoadFromStream(memStream);
    frxReport1.DesignReport();
  finally
    memStream.Free;
  end;
end;

function TForm1.frxDesigner1SaveReport(Report: TfrxReport;
  SaveAs: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  memStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
   if not SaveAs then
   try
     memStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
     frxReport1.SaveToStream(memStream);
     memStream.Position:=0;
     ADOTable1.Edit;
     ADOTable1ReportBLOB.LoadFromStream(memStream);
     ADOTable1.Post;
   finally
     memStream.Free;
   end;
end;
```

You may contact FR support and get full demo project

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the report is stored inside a bob field of one of the tables in the database, you can simply create a stream with `TDataSet.CreateBlobStream` and use that with `TfrxReport.LoadFromStream`.

Comment: And when you need to send a new version of the report to your user, you will tell them "simply create a stream to save the report to a BLOB in the database" :-)

Comment: Usually that is done inside the updater without being noticed by the user. The user doesn't even have the concept of a report in a file. He associates a report with the printed output.

Comment: Sure it's possible to write an updater that writes a file in a database. It just adds useless complexity. Unless you have specific requirements, a regular file is the way to go.

Comment: That requirements don't have to be specific. They are quite common. But this is not the place to discuss requirements. The question was pretty specific, though.

Comment: @Olivier I heard about systems which even stored their DLLs and EXEs as database BLOBs - for the sake of centralized by source decentralized by applying updates. As soon as new versions were uploaded into DB - each and every client automagically updated itself. Without any central dictionary of "where did we even installed that app?"

Comment: I also wonder if `.fr3` files are compressed or not? i'd perhaps applied Z-Std or at least Zip compression when storing reports into database and decompressed on reading

Comment: I tried ur solution and i think u r right everything seems ok but when i load report it loads empty .. didn't know if i cant' find solutin till tomorow i will post my code thanks @uwe raabe